# In Hive, if(field1=field2=field3=0,'0','1') is not giving expected results

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

In Hive query, in the single IF condition, I provided multiple fields check, but not giving the expected results.

Query:

```
select ID, field1, field2, field3, 
       if(field1=field2=field3=0,'0','1') as compare_check
from input_table;
```

input_table

[image: Input_table]

Output results:

[image: Output Results]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple conditions wont work here. Could you please separate all conditions? Also make sure all fields doesn't have any extra space etc. around them.

```
if(field1=field2 and field1=field3 
and field1=0,'0','1')
```

There is another way to do it -

```
If (field1+field2+field3=0,0,1)
```